# Sequence order in the column oriented formats chapter of book Hadoop the definitive guide?

Tags: hadoop, hive, column-oriented

In page 137 of *Hadoop: The definitive guide 4th edition*, it talks about column oriented formats file and shows a picture below.

[image]

In the RCFile, why the sequence order of numbers is `1,4,2,5,3,6,7,10,8,11,9,12` rather than `1,4,7,10,2,5,8,11,3,6,9,12`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, **RC is not columnar file**, it is **Record Columnar** file.
RC as well as ORC are splittable. This means you do not read all the file to get only few rows and it can be read in parallel by many containers. And this is why we need splits.

**Splits contain rows that are grouped together** and can be read independent of each other, and at the same time **columns are also grouped inside splits**. Similar data can be compressed better, so if columns are grouped together, it improves compression.  In your example one split contains **only two rows**, but it can contain 10000 or more rows.

What the official [**documentation**](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/RCFile) says about RC file:

- As row-store, RCFile guarantees that data in the same row are located
  in the same node.
- As column-store, RCFile can exploit column-wise data compression and
  skip unnecessary column reads.

Also read about [**ORC**](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+ORC). Using indexes in ORC, stripes can be easily filtered on the lowest level. This feature is called predicate push down.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! There is also an important point in the documentation you 've mentioned is: RCFile stores table data in a flat file consisting of binary key/value pairs. It first partitions rows horizontally into row splits, and then it vertically partitions each row split in a columnar way.